# Netty: How to make sure Channel.close() was fired by the I/O thread

Tags: netty

I am using Netty 3.6.2, here is my pipeline factory pseudocode：

```
private final static ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(8, 4194304, 4194304, 5L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
    ChannelPipeline p = pipeline();
    p.addLast("frameDecoder", protobufFrameDecoder);
    p.addLast("protobufDecoder", protobufDecoder);
    p.addLast("executor", new ExecutionHandler(executor));
    p.addLast("handler", handler);
    p.addLast("frameEncoder", protobufFrameEncoder);
    p.addLast("protobufEncoder", protobufEncoder);
    return p;
}
```

in this way, the handler's messageReceived() was called in different thread pool instead of worker thread pool, now I want to close channel in case some exception happened in messageReceived(), but according to here: http://netty.io/wiki/thread-model.html,

> any upstream events triggered as a side effect of the downstream event
>   must be fired from the I/O thread.

simply call ctx.getChannel().close() is not safe in exceptionCaught(), I am trying to use this way to solve this issue,

```
NettyServerSocketFactory.getWorkerExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       channel.close();
   }
});
```

here is NettyServerSocketFactory code:

```
public class NettyServerSocketFactory extends NioServerSocketChannelFactory {

private static Executor bossExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
private static Executor workerExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public static Executor getBossExecutor() {
    return bossExecutor;
}

public static Executor getWorkerExecutor() {
    return workerExecutor;
}

public NettyServerSocketFactory() {
    super(bossExecutor, workerExecutor);
}
}
```

but it seems not work, any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Channel#close() triggers a downstream event that will ventually reach the ChannelSink, where the event is "handed over" to the worker associated with the channel for further processing. The worker will eventually fire a channel closed event, and the worker will make sure that the event is sent upstream on the IO thread.

This is how it currently works, maybe the document you are referring to is discussing a previous situation, where the event indeed was delivered on the calling thread.